# jQuery: add click event to specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a small jquery problem:

My code is like this:

```
<div id="select-word-5" class="select-word-link"> - some content - </div>
<div id="select-5" class="select"> - some content - </div>
```

I have throughout my document several select-word-link and select divs.

I want to add a click event to the first div, that reacts just to the second div.

My idea was to loop through all the "select-x" elements, but i think there is a much better way?

```
$('.select-word-link').each(function()
{

    var id = this.id;
    var idLink = this.id.replace("-word", "");


    $('.select').each(function()
    {

        if (idLink == this.id)
        {


          $(id).click(function() {
            alert("this does not work");

        });

    });


});
```

Comment: 1. IDs must be UNIQUE. Use class. 2. Add the event to the nested element and use stopPropagation to not bubble up

Comment: You want to add a click listener? If so you need to use the on('click', function() {}) syntax. Also you could simply use the next/prev function if your html place both divs next to each other.

Comment: As an addition to my answer, I think there might be a simpler way of solve your problem all together ;-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this easier by triggering an action on an event.

```
$('#select-5').click(function(){
    alert('Does this work?');
});

$('.select-word-link').click(function(){
    $('#select-5').trigger('click'); // will behave as if #select-5 is clicked.
});
```

Info: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

More advanced:

```
$('#select-5').click(function(){
    alert('Does this work?');
});

$('#select-6').click(function(){
    alert('Does this work?');
});

// etc

$('.select-word-link').click(function(){
    var selectId  = this.id.replace('-word', '');
    $('#'+selectId).trigger('click'); // will behave as if #select-5 is clicked.
});
```

Comment: This already looks really good :)Just a small question: if i use the last code with the "select-word-link", do i still need to make a click event for every "select" or can i use a universal approach too? The JS code for every click event is the same (its just the content between the divs that is different, thats why i need to use ids for the links)

Comment: Got it! Just replace the trigger ($(selectId).trigger....) with:

("#"+selectID).XXXX And then my jQuery Code to by executed :)

Comment: Awesome, as a tip: you might want to investigate the usage of classes and ids a bit more, often when you need to use something like the `replace` function there is another way. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

maybe this code help you

```
    $(".select-word-link").click(function(){
    $(this).next().hide();
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('.select-word-link').first().on('click',function(){
   // you code goes here
})
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just select the first element with a class `select-word-link`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to trigger click `next()` element not all `.select`

```js
$(".word").click(function() {
  var selectId = this.id.replace('-word', '');
  console.log(selectId);
   $('#'+selectId).trigger('click');
});

$(".next").click(function() {
  alert($(this).html());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="select-word-5" class="select-word-link word">- some content 5-</div>
<div id="select-word-6" class="select-word-link word">- some content 6-</div>
<div id="select-word-7" class="select-word-link word">- some content 7-</div>etc.
<div id="select-5" class="select-word-link next">- some content next 5-</div>
<div id="select-6" class="select-word-link next">- some content next 6-</div>
<div id="select-7" class="select-word-link next">- some content next 7-</div>
```

Comment: you can find next `.select`

Comment: the problem is, that select is not always the next element. my code looks like this:

`<div id="select-word-5" class="select-word-link"> - some content - </div>
<div id="select-word-6" class="select-word-link"> - some content - </div>
<div id="select-word-7" class="select-word-link"> - some content - </div>

etc. 

<div id="select-5" class="select-word-link"> - some content - </div>
<div id="select-6" class="select-word-link"> - some content - </div>
<div id="select-7" class="select-word-link"> - some content - </div>`

Comment: As per `select-word-link` bind click it triggers click multiple times recursively. You can do that by adding two class `word` and `next` to element and you can trigger specific click.

Comment: Do `console.log(selectId);` you can see that `select-word-link` trigger `select-word-link` it self of `div` without `word`. and recursive click triggers. That it will not work and a bad code to do this.

Comment: In your question you are having `.select` and `.select-word-link` and in your comment you are only have `select-word-link`. If you are only have all `select-word-link` then it makes recursive call else works fine. @mangotasche

Answer (score 0):

jQuery as CSS uses `#` selector to identify that this string is an Id.
e.g.

`<div id="someId"></div>`

and you execute this code:

```
$('#someId')
```

this will select the DOM object that has the Id `someId`

while `id` property returns the id of the DOM object without the selector `#` i.e. this jQuery code:

```
var id = $('#someId').get(0).id
```

will initialize the variable `id` to `'someId'`

Thus, in your code add `'#'` in the selector

```
$('#' + id).click(function() {
            alert("this does not work");

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

very simple solution

```
$('#select-5 , .select-word-link').click(function () {
// your code
});
```

If you want trigger same functionality from 2 or more different div ids or classes or combination of both then put separated by , like '#select-5 , .select-word-link' as shown in above example.